# Python retrieve google drive document to variable

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-drive-api

I want to retrieve an `xlsx` file from Google Drive directly into a variable in python. I do not have, nor can I get access to the Google Drive API for the account that has access to this file. I also cannot gain access to this file with an account that has API access.

I've previously worked with selenium, and have managed to write a script that downloads the file into a directory of my choosing:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from pathlib import Path
import os

import logging

'''
my_data_dir = ...
my_profile = ...
...
'''

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={my_data_dir}')

chrome_options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={my_profile}')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--verbose')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": os.path.abspath("./driver_downloads"),
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')


def chrome():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': os.path.abspath("./driver_downloads")}
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
    return driver

driver = chrome()
driver.get(drive_url)

logger.debug("Waiting for element to load...")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'[aria-label^="{filename}"]')))

xlsx_file = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'[aria-label^="{filename}"]')
ActionChains(driver).context_click(xlsx_file).perform()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role="menu"] div[role="menuitem"] div[data-tooltip="Download"][aria-label="Download"]')))

logger.debug("Download button found. Clicking...")

download_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role="menu"] div[role="menuitem"] div[data-tooltip="Download"][aria-label="Download"]')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(download_button).click().perform()
```

This script works *fine*, but:

- I want a way to skip writing the file to disk and reading it later on in my code.
- The script relies heavily on drive's current structure, and I'd prefer to not worry about future incompatibilities.

The end goal is to write a script to read the file, extract new info a third party may have written to it, and load this new data into a database I have full access to. I don't mind changing to a library other than selenium.